# Set<Object> vs List<Object>?

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, set

I have a Object which contains an id and some attributes for that id.

```
public class Data {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

Currently I have defined it in the Request Object as :

```
public class Request {
    private List<Data> dataList;
}
```

Is there going to make any difference with List vs Set if I know that I will ll probably never encounter the same id (content) in the request.

Overall for this usecase, which is better ? List vs Set ?

Comment: A `List` can be randomly accessed, has an order, and a `Set` doesn't necessarily do. You should also clearly define what you mean by "better", and describe more about your use case.

Comment: @Sweeper just that If I know there won't be any duplicate id and values - is that necessary for me to use Set ?

Comment: I would just note that the term "id" implies uniqueness in every context I've ever encountered. If an "id" wasn't unique, how could it "identify" something? Whether or not you want to use a List or a Set is a question of how the consumer of this data structure will process it and the tradeoffs between using a List or a Set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there going to make any difference with List vs Set

`List` and `Set` have different semantics. A `List` is an ordered collection of items that allows duplicate entries. A `Set` is an unordered collection of items that allows no duplicates. (there are also some special variants that combine ordering and uniqueness like `SortedSet` and `NavigableSet`)

> I know that I will ll probably never encounter the same id

The uniqueness of `Set` is by default ensured by your objects `equals` method. If you want your `Data` objects to be unique "by id" you have to implement custom `equals` and `hashCode` methods within your `Data` class
that check for equal id.

> Overall for this usecase, which is better?

I can't see any use case in your question.

If you need uniqueness take a `Set`. If you just need a collection of items take a `List`.

There are of course other use cases, too. For example, if you need to check whether your collection already contains an item or not. With a `List` you have to iterate over all elements and check for equality. When using for instance an `HashSet` it will just compute the `hashCode` of your object  (with an `equals` check afterwards) and has the answer, which is much faster for large collections.

Comment: "When using a Set it will just compute the hashCode of your object" that is true for HashSet, but not for Set generally.

Comment: @davmac Yeah true, that's why it's called **Hash**Set. Other `Set` implementations use different techniques. Just wanted to make clear that `Set`s in general are optimized for fast `contains`, because `contains` is needed for the uniqueness, which is the main purpose of a `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that two objects are equal or not, Java uses `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

These are default method of any object. While putting an object in the set you may get wrong output because default implementation can give you same hash code for two objects. 
Hence is it advisable to implement both `equals` and `hashCode` methods in custom classes.

Map and Set collection use hash code for storing the object.
However, List is an `ordered` collection and you can check whether same id exist or not in the objects before adding the object to the list. But again it would be a performance hit for big object pool.

Comment: Java only uses equals for compare two objects